# Kurtosis in Aggregate function

Tags: python

Kurtosis function  when used in aggregate block, by default uses the fisher definition .
 I want the Pearson calculation to be used . And to do that the Bool "fisher=False" need to set on kurtosis function

But get error when i set that on code

Here is Original code that works fine with fisher definition for kurtosis

```
df1=df.groupby(['EngID','ncyc']).agg(

    {
        'derived_Field6' : [np.mean,np.std ,skew,kurtosis],
        'derived_Field13' : [np.mean,np.std ,skew,kurtosis],
        'derived_Field20' : [np.mean,np.std ,skew,kurtosis],
        'derived_Field21' : [np.mean,np.std ,skew,kurtosis],
        'derived_rul' : [np.mean],
        'EngID' : [np.mean],

    }
)
```

When i tried this

```
derived_Field6' : [np.mean,np.std ,skew,kurtosis(fisher= False)],
```

get an error 
" kurtosis() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a' "

Please advise the right syntax

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to "freeze" some function arguments. In your case:

```py
import functools
from scipy.stats import kurtosis

kurtosis_pearson = functools.partial(kurtosis, fisher=False)
```

Then, you can pass `kurtosis_pearson` to your aggregate function.